# How to fix the apt-get -f install error

Tags: apt, dpkg

I am getting continuous error when I run the command `sudo apt-get -f install`
The output of the command is as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
default-jre-headless icedtea-7-jre-jamvm openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless openjdk-7-jre-lib
Suggested packages:
  fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho ttf-telugu-fonts ttf-oriya-fonts ttf-kannada-fonts ttf-bengali-fonts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  default-jre-headless icedtea-7-jre-jamvm openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless openjdk-7-jre-lib
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/
satish@satish-Inspiron-N5010 ~ $
```

please guide ASAP

Comment: You either have another process using APT or the lock is stuck. Delete the lock if you're sure nothing else is using APT (like the system updater)

Comment: @DamonGant how to do that??

Comment: `sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/lock`

Comment: Done. What should I do next?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get -f install` again after doing @DamonGant's comment above.